# Can't seem to figure out why bubble sort is not working in java

Tags: java, bubble-sort

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[]={13,33,1,32,8,10,11,6};
    bubbleSort(a);


}

public static void bubbleSort(int []a){
int temp=0;
    int n= a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++ ){

        for(int j=1; j<n-1;j++){  

            if(a[j-1]>a[j]){

                temp=a[j-1];
                a[j-1]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;

            }
        }System.out.println(a[i]);
    }
}
```

I don't seem to get how do i manage to get such random sort out of the algorithm!? 1 and 8 don't even appear at all and 13  shows 3 times.

THE RESULT :
13 
13 
10 
11 
13 
32 
33 
6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes I could found.

- I remove your print statement and put it outside of the loop.
- Your second loop looks like this. 
  `for(int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++){`
  I replaced with this code line.
  `for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {`

Plase, try following code.

```
public class BubbleSort{

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      int a[] = {13, 33, 1, 32, 8, 10, 11, 6};
      bubbleSort(a);

   }

   public static void bubbleSort(int[] a) {
      int temp = 0;
      int n = a.length;

      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {
               //swap elements  
               temp = a[j - 1];
               a[j - 1] = a[j];
               a[j] = temp;
            }

         }

      }
      // print array after sorting. 
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
         System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
      }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`j` should iterate all the way up until `n` (not until `n-1`).

Change:

```
for(int j=1; j<n-1; j++){
```

to:

```
for(int j=1; j<n; j++){
```

and your bubble sort will work.

Answer (score 0):

Two main issues here:

1. as @alfasin says "j should iterate all the way up until n (not until n-1)."
2. the `System.out.println` should be performed after all the operations have been executed, not during the sorting process itself.

The following should work:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={13,33,1,32,8,10,11,6};


        int result[] = bubbleSort(a);

        for(int i:result)
            System.out.println(i);  
    }

    public static int[] bubbleSort(int []a){
    int temp=0;
        int n= a.length;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            for(int j=1; j<n;j++){  
                if(a[j-1]>a[j]) {
                    temp=a[j-1];
                    a[j-1]=a[j];
                    a[j]=temp;
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second level iteration is stopping one step before it should. And you are printing the array elements at the wrong stage.

```
public static void bubbleSort(int []a){
    int temp=0;
    int n= a.length;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++ ){
        for(int j=1; j<n;j++){
            if(a[j-1] > a[j]){
                temp=a[j-1]; a[j-1]=a[j]; a[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i: a) {
        System.out.print(i+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output is not quite useful, since you are printing valies while sorting is in progress.

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++ ){
     System.out.println(a[i]);
}
```

Use this at the end of the result. @alfasin already pointed out another bug.

Answer (score 0):

Besides what alfashin already said, that your loop should go to n, not n-1 is that you do not output your final result, but intermediate results at calibration step i:

System.out.println(a[i]);

Make sure to output after you finished sorting

Answer (score 0):

On top of the two mistakes everyone mentioned already, it's also worth noting that your logic on how to perform a bubble sort is sub optimal.

You're using an outer for loop which assumes you'll need to perform the inner loop a consistent number of time. But really it all depends on the list you're working with.

I'll use this fixed version of your code to demonstrate it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {13, 33, 1, 32, 8, 10, 11, 6};
    bubbleSort(a);

}

public static void bubbleSort(int[] a) {
    int temp;
    int n = a.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {

            if (a[j - 1] > a[j]) {

                temp = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
}
```

Right now the outer for loop runs n times, so 8 times. And you get a sorted list as output.

```
[1, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 32, 33]
```

But what happens if you run it less than 8 times? Try it by replacing n by 6. Output:

```
[1, 6, 8, 10, 11, 13, 32, 33]
```

Same result, that means you run the sort twice on an already sorted list. This can be an issue if you have a list of 1000 integers that is already sorted, because you'll loop 1000 times for nothing.

From wikipedia: "The only significant advantage that bubble sort has over most other implementations [...] is that the ability to detect that the list is sorted efficiently is built into the algorithm. When the list is already sorted (best-case), the complexity of bubble sort is only O(n)."

So you're essentially ruining the only reason to use bubble sort.

You'll want to use some other kind of loop, good luck.